# Adding fields to objects is not working javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an array of objects. If they meet a certain condition, I add another property to the object and save it to my database (Mongo). However, the additional property never shows up in the db. I have logged it to console just before saving to confirm it's there, but it never shows up when I check with the mongo shell.

```js
function nearbyPlaces(distance, unit) {
 db.Places.find({}, function (err, places) {
  var distance = Number(distance) || 1000
  var unit = unit || 'km'

  for(var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
   var nearby = []
   var start = {}
   if(places[i].latitude && places[i].longitude){
    start.latitude = places[i].latitude
    start.longitude = places[i].longitude
   }
   for(var j = 0; j < places.length; j++){
    var end = {}
    if(i !== j && places[j].latitude && places[j].longitude) {
     end.latitude = places[j].latitude
     end.longitude = places[j].longitude
     var dist = haversine(start, end, {unit: unit})
     if(dist <= distance) {
      if(places[j]) {
       var temp = places[j]
       temp.distance = dist
       nearby.push(temp)
      }
     }
    }
   }
   //console.log('distance is',nearby[0].distance)
            // this prints out correctly
   
   var record = {
    origin: places[i].origin,
    latitude: places[i].latitude,
    longitude: places[i].longitude,
    nearby: nearby,
    max_distance: distance,
    unit: unit
   }

   console.log('saving record')

   var thingy = new db.Nearby(record)
   thingy.save(function (err) {
    if(err) {
     console.log(err)
    }
    if(!err) {
     console.log('saved')
    }

   })
   
  }
 })
}
```

```js
// This line comes from index.js
exports.Nearby = Mongoose.model('Nearby', require('./nearby'))

// The Nearby schema
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var db = require('./index')

var trimmedString = {type: String, trim: true}

var NearbyPlaces = new mongoose.Schema({
 origin: String,
 latitude: Number, // latitude in degrees
 longitude: Number,
 nearby: Array,
 max_distance: Number,
 unit: String
})

NearbyPlaces.index({origin: 1})
NearbyPlaces.index({distance: 1})
NearbyPlaces.index({unit: 1})

module.exports = NearbyPlaces
```

nearby[x].distance never shows up. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Can you edit the code so that we can see when/where "nearby" is initialized?

Comment: @dbenson I've included the full function

Comment: Does your mongo db use mongoose for its scheme?

Comment: @Tony yes it does. nearby is an Array type.

Comment: Show your "schema" definition for the `Nearby` model. Chances are your properties are not defined correctly. You are also doing the whole process wrong. Read up on [Geospatial indexes and Queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) where there are much better alternatives to the code you are writing.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I know this is an n^2 algorithm, but the data set can't have more than 3200 entries by virtue of what types of places these are (number of train stations doesn't change too quickly). If I index on distance then I can get back a document in log2(n) time and it already has all the nearby locations in the nearby array. Why is that a bad method? It takes slow computation up front but allows future fast access and it's acceptable because it could be implemented quickly and wouldn't matter after the first run.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I take it Mongo probably knows how much lat and lon change corresponds to a certain distance and indexes on a location object, so it would be able to find a location within x distance in log2(n) but also need to repeat that for each location within that distance giving it overall n(log2(n)) performance which is definitely more scalable. If all my assumptions are correct I still get faster access time. I was thinking of other ways I could write a more efficient algorithm, but this is a side project and I wanted to move forward, so this was acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
var temp = places[j].toObject();
temp.distance = dist;
nearby.push(temp);
```